# Dictionary with occurence of length of words

Tags: python, dictionary

My function takes a dictionary as input and then displays a text bar plot in the console. That is, it should "print" to the screen the bar plot. The labels of the plot of the are the keys in the dictionary and the bar lengths are determined by the values of the keys.

For example using this dictionary:

```
{4:2, 3:5, 10:1, 8:1, 5:1}
```

the plot would look like this:

```
keys|values         
----+-------------       
03|#####       
04|##   
05|#  
08|#  
10|#
```

The labels (keys) should be displayed in sorted order when making the plot. Each label (key) should be displayed with leading zeros so that each has the same number of digits in it. At the moment all my function does is print the dictionary of a file that has the following sentence:

> and then the last assignment ended and everyone was sad

```
def wordLengthStats(filename):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    wordcount={}
    for line in file.read().split():
        if line not in wordcount:
            wordcount[line] = 1
        else:
            wordcount[line] += 1
    for k,v in wordcount.items():
        print (k, v)
    return None

def main():

    d = wordLengthStats("sample.txt")
    print("d should be { 3:5, 4:2, 5:1, 8:1, 10:1} ")
    print("d is", d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The sentence is just an example, I am trying to make it so that any input should work. Any help on approaching this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [collections.Counter](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html) will likely be useful for such a task.

Comment: @evadeflow how so?

Comment: What, precisely, is your question? On what feature of your program are you stuck?

Comment: @coding101, LMc's answer pretty much lays it out for you. I didn't answer because your question has *so* many [duplicates](https://www.google.com/search?q=count+frequency+of+characters+in+Python+site%3Astackoverflow.com) on SO.

Comment: @evadeflow well I couldn't find the answer I was looking for but if you see a question similar to mine I would love to take a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension to create tuples (key, value*"#") for key, values in the items of the dictionary and sort this list:

```
d = { 4:2, 3:5, 10:1, 8:1, 5:1}
sorted([(k,'#'*v) for k, v in d.items()])
```

You can get the desired output by iterating over these tuples in the list and use the following print format:

```
for x in sorted([(k,'#'*v) for k, v in d.items()]):
    print "{}|{}".format(x[0], x[1])
```

To add "0" to k < 10:

```
if x[0] < 10:
    print "0{}|{}".format(x[0], x[1])
else: 
    print "{}|{}".format(x[0], x[1])
```

Comment: any idea how to get the key values to have leading zeros?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter

def wordLengthStats(filename):
    counts=Counter(i.strip() for i in open(filename).readlines())
    for (k,v) in sorted(counts.items(),key=lambda x: x[-1],reverse=True):
        print("{}|{}".format(k.zfill(2),'#'*v))
```

The `Counter` function will create a dictionary that has frequencies of all the lines in `filename`.

`sorted(counts.items(),key=lambda x: x[-1],reverse=True)` says sort the items in descending order (`reverse=True`) by the last position (`x[-1]` in `counts.items()`, which would be the frequencies.

Lastly the `.zfill` string method pads `k` with leading zeros for the `print` statement.

**Example:**

---

Fake file, 'fake.txt':

> 3 
>   3
>   3
>   3
>   3
>   4
>   4
>   5
>   8
>   10

---

```
>>> wordLengthStats('fake.txt')
03|#####
04|##
05|#
08|#
10|#
```

In this instance `counts` looks like:

```
{'3': 5, '4': 2, '5': 1, '8': 1, '10': 1}
```

and `sorted(counts.items(),key=lambda x: x[-1],reverse=True)` looks like (note the most frequent item is first):

```
[('3', 5), ('4', 2), ('5', 1), ('8', 1), ('10', 1)]
```

If you don't want to sort by frequency and instead by key then do `sorted(counts.items())`